# What Is The Rectangular Pipe Structure/Loop Constructed To Reduce HighRise Water Supply Pressure DownStream From Roof Tank?

Tags: pressure

[image: Rectangular Pipe Loop]

This Pipe Loops installed in series downstream from highrise rooftop storage tank should serve to reduce Water Pressure supplied to lower-floor households.

I tried all kinds of Google Search terms, but found no result close enough in explaining what this Pipe Loop is officially called and how exactly it is supposed to work, like:

(1) Does such a loop reduce water pressure? If so, how does it work?

(2) Does the loop reduce Static Water Pressure downstream?

Are they any web resources that further explains how the loop reduces water pressure?

Or could it be that a PRV/Pressure Reducing Valve is central to the function in the curious loop structure and the loop itself is not as interesting?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the pressure regulator is the device in the rightmost section of the loop, near the gauge. Such a loop, with all the associated valves, would enable the pressure regulator and/or gauge to be replaced or maintained without interrupting the water supply to the entire building. Notice also, that the valves in the loop have been "secured" by cable ties, to prevent anyone from adjusting the valves unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks Fred. That makes sense. I read similar explanation elsewhere, but for different pipe structure, so I didn't know that was it. If this is all to it, then, it is now appearing quite simple! Thanks for the enlightenment!